# MS Access VBA : Add "Run Saved Imports" to Form button

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have the following code :

```
Private Sub Command66_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Object"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "AccountingStandard"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

After the deletion is complete I like to add some code that Runs/Opens the "Saved Imports" (from the External Database tab). Is this possible? What type of code do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the dialog, use

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSavedImports
```

All menu commands are available in `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmd...`, but you need to find the correct one in the list...

To run a specific import, use

```
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "myImport"
```